# Django For-Loop and Div ID

Tags: jquery, django, twitter-bootstrap, django-templates

I am trying to loop through a portfolio but hitting a snag. I am using Bootstrap and would like to use Modal light box for images. I am having an issue looping through a div that would allow my lightbox to have an absolute_url. When I loop through urls are changing but when you click the image to bring up the light box it is only pulling the first div because of the div id. I am not a java or jquery guy only know django and python and stumped.

index.html

```
    <section id="three" class="no-padding">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row no-gutter">
        {% for sites in portfolio %}
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                <a href="#galleryModal" class="gallery-box" data-toggle="modal" data-src="{{sites.image.url}}">
                    <img src="{{sites.image.url}}" class="img-responsive" alt="Image 1">
                    <div class="gallery-box-caption">
                        <div class="gallery-box-content">
                            <div>
                                <i class="icon-lg ion-ios-search"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div id="galleryModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <img src="//placehold.it/1200x700/222?text=..." id="galleryImage" class="img-responsive" />
                        <p>
                            <br/>
                            <a href="{{ sites.get_absolute_url }}"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" aria-hidden="true">View Details <i class="ion-document"></i></button></a>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close <i class="ion-android-close"></i></button>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

views.py

```
def home(request):
about = About.objects.latest('timestamp')
concepts = Concept.objects.order_by('?')[:3]
portfolio = Portfolio.objects.all()[:6]
template = "index.html"
context = {
    "about": about,
    "concepts": concepts,
    "portfolio": portfolio,
}
return render(request, template, context)
```

js

```
$('#galleryModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
   $('#galleryImage').attr("src",$(e.relatedTarget).data("src"));
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to add `{{ forloop.counter }}` to your id attributes :

```
<div id="galleryModal_{{ forloop.counter }}" ...> id="galleryImage"
```

and

```
<a href="#galleryModal" ...>
<img src="..." id="galleryImage_{{forloop.counter}}" ..>
```

then js for each block:

```
$('#galleryModal_1').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {   $('#galleryImage_1').attr("src",$(e.relatedTarget).data("src"));
```

});

see [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#for) for using `forloop.counter`

Comment: Thanks I was close just did not change galleryImage when I tried. Thank you so much for your help I would upvote but do not have enough reputation